# Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?

Tags: lan

I have 2 LANs in my own PC & 2 Routers (TP-Link WR941N each) with 2 internet accounts (512Kbps each) connected to the same ISP signal & company using NanoStation 5 from ubnt.

As you know the connections work separately by default! (I use Windows 7 64bit)

Can I merge them to get double speed (download/upload simultaneously) using regedit or special software or any other method?

I'd be much appreciated if u could help me doing that

Best Regards, Salaam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two ethernet ports](http://superuser.com/questions/23922/combining-two-ethernet-ports)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate as that question is just about the LAN whereas this is about the internet connection as well.

Comment: The last post showed the bottleneck was on the receiving end.  Doesn't seem to matter if the 2 lines come from ISP directly or router.

Answer (score 7):

You can use two connections in one Windows machine, but you can't use the full bandwidth of both connections in a single download because the server at the other end will only respond to one IP address so, as both of your internet connections would each have their own external IP address, you'll only get a response from a given server down one connection at a time.

All is not lost though! As other posters have mentioned, you can use multi-WAN routers to load-balance connections (so two simultaneous downloads would be split across the two connections, for example) but on a Windows PC with two network connections you might be able to use [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258487/EN-US/).

**Update:**

My apologies! I linked the Windows 2000 article. Rather than search for the Windows 7 one, I've just gone and tested it myself - go to your Network Connections list and for each of your two network adaptors, right click, choose "Properties", "Internet Protocol Version 4 Properties", "Advanced", then uncheck "Automatic Metric" at the bottom and enter 0 for each one.

Windows will now treat both connections equally and randomly assign sessions between the two. That's about as good as you can do without using a third party program.

Comment: Wow, that's neat. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be called "link aggregation" these days, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Use_on_network_interface_cards):

> Microsoft Windows does not natively support link aggregation (at least up to Windows Server 2008).[7] However, some manufacturers provide software for aggregation on their multiport NICs at the device-driver layer.

So if you have the same 2 NICs, I might start by looking to see if the manufacturer has any special drivers for them.

Comment: They're (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller), thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is setup a bonded link to your ISP. You will have to see whether they support this, but if they do you will probably have to pay a setup fee and maybe have a special router at your end, which you often have to pay for.

The next best option is to use a load balancing router - this has two WAN/xDSL/Cable ports that allow you to use it with two ISP connections and the router will distribute the data flow between the two routes. This isn't the same as true Bonding, but is cheaper to setup as it needs no specific help/kit from the ISP - in fact, it will also work with two different ISPs.