# Does Load Balancer Improve Speed To VPN connection

Tags: vpn, performance, internet

I am planning to setup a load balancer connected with multiple ISP.

I will be than that load balanced internet to connect to a Premium VPN service (like purevpn or so) to access youtube and other site not available in my region.

Will load balance will improve speed , Or load balancer doesnt work with single connection PPTP to one server (i believe)?

Comment: Why bother? If your purpose is to access content not available in your country, a simple VPN service would suffice. There's no need to subscribe to two ISPs.

Comment: actually my internet are not reliable, and wireless, wimax here have limited speed which makes it worst when browsing via VPN connected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/240122/can-i-combine-two-lans-into-one-to-get-double-speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A load balancer will not improve the speed of connections without special hardware on the receiving end. Multi-homing (using multiple Internet connections) improves throughput (bandwidth) but not speed. Two 1Mbps lines are not the same as a 2Mbps line, because a single connection will only ever be able to transfer data at a rate of 1Mbps. Unless you are using a protocol which involves multiple incoming and outgoing connections, you won't see much benefit from load-balancing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I purchased switchboard service from www.connectify.me which works pretty much same way as you told me, but infact my speed droped significantly. I believe their vpn service is pretty slow.

Do you know any easy method to combine multiple internet for fast streaming?

Probably any other VPN service from which i can benefit using load balancing.