# Multiple ISP link aggregation

Tags: networking, router

Can we get additional speed of multiple ISP's?

For example:

isp1 = 5 mbps
isp2 = 6 mbps

total = 11 mbps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster internet](http://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet), [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/240122/can-i-combine-two-lans-into-one-to-get-double-speed)

Comment: Maybe you can setup a vpn connection to a remote host that has a higher bandwidth...

Answer (score 0):

Link aggregation only works in networks where you have 2 network cards that can do it, hooked up to a router that can do link aggregation also. You'll be looking at doubled network speed in this case. But you can't use multiple net connections in the same manner. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: There is this thing called Connectify Dispatch that will help you do that, but only to an extent. Distributed services such as bittorrent will see the benifits, browser not so much.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Even in multi-homed corporate environments with enormous budgets with a staff of professional network engineers, all inbound traffic to a particular host address sent from an arbitrary remote network will be delivered via only one ISP at a time. Load-balancing strategies can be used to make certain remote networks prefer one ISP over the other, but for an individual session, its top inbound rate cannot be faster than the fastest link to the ISP.

In the case of identical sized pipes to multiple ISPs, per-packet outbound load balancing can be configured on even modest enterprise-level routers, for an overall increase in outbound bandwidth, but it's unlikely that this extra bandwidth will result in a particular session's transfer rate to exceed the rate of a single pipe.