# Using two ISP connections simultaneously to add stability in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, router, home-networking, load-balancer

I have two internet connection from two different ISP. ADSL on eth0 and 4G on wlan0. Is there any way that if one ISP fails, the other take over automatically without a physical router and by Host OS (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125114/using-wifi-port-as-redundant-link)

Comment: @xenoid: I have serious doubts that bonding could _possibly_ work with two different upstream ISPs.

Comment: How are you going to detect if one "ISP fails"? Ping probes in regular intervals? Router information? Choose a method, implement it, write a script to update routes when the status changes. Sorry, no out-of-the-box way AFAIK.

Comment: @grawity For plenty of uses with soft connections, it would (web surfing, mail..). Of course, a long HTTP transfer would get interrupted.

Comment: What router? Typically this is not handled by the PC regardless of OS, but by the router... many high-end SOHO routers and most commercial grade routers can handle this smoothly and automatically as this is actually a common application.

Comment: [Load balancing with multiple ISP, two routers and firewall](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19721/16289), [Multiple ISP link aggregation](https://superuser.com/q/848001/241386)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart as even you noted in your solution, this requires telling the computer to operate as a router (pfsense), as phuclv notes, router link redundancy and load balancing are questions that have been asked and answered here before.

Comment: What makes you say that? One of the suggested answers is a SU answer.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart sure, any suggestion? I just added `without a physical router and by Host OS`

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Also I've changed the script to exactly what I want: https://gist.github.com/Daniyal-Javani/6ea632dbbbb744f0e4f6dd0004b0351e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never personally tried to do this from the host OS. 
But after a back and forth, I decided to dig around on the internet to see if I could find what you are looking for.

I found an example script for gateway fail-over at gist.github.com created by the user "Apsu". you can download the bash script [here.](https://gist.github.com/Apsu/5021255)

You will have to modify this to your specific setup, add your interface names, gateway addresses & you should be good to go.

### Script for the Host OS:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set defaults if not provided by environment
CHECK_DELAY=${CHECK_DELAY:-5}
CHECK_IP=${CHECK_IP:-8.8.8.8}
PRIMARY_IF=${PRIMARY_IF:-eth0}
PRIMARY_GW=${PRIMARY_GW:-1.2.3.4}
BACKUP_IF=${BACKUP_IF:-eth1}
BACKUP_GW=${BACKUP_GW:-2.3.4.5}

# Compare arg with current default gateway interface for route to healthcheck IP
gateway_if() {
  [[ "$1" = "$(ip r g "$CHECK_IP" | sed -rn 's/^.*dev ([^ ]*).*$/\1/p')" ]]
}

# Cycle healthcheck continuously with specified delay
while sleep "$CHECK_DELAY"
do
  # If healthcheck succeeds from primary interface
  if ping -I "$PRIMARY_IF" -c1 "$CHECK_IP" &>/dev/null
  then
    # Are we using the backup?
    if gateway_if "$BACKUP_IF"
    then # Switch to primary
      ip r d default via "$BACKUP_GW" dev "$BACKUP_IF"
      ip r a default via "$PRIMARY_GW" dev "$PRIMARY_IF"
    fi
  else
    # Are we using the primary?
    if gateway_if "$PRIMARY_IF"
    then # Switch to backup
      ip r d default via "$PRIMARY_GW" dev "$PRIMARY_IF"
      ip r a default via "$BACKUP_GW" dev "$BACKUP_IF"
    fi
  fi
done
```

---

### With network hardware:

There are considerable advantages to using a router for this function, as opposed to just fail-over from the host OS. What immediately comes to mind is using both connections bandwidth simultaneously. (Fully utilizing both ISP connections)

You can use PFsense / OpenSense as a dual WAN router.
(Most old PC hardware will work.) I believe DD-WRT supported routers are also capable of WAN fail-over with some tweaking. Or you could go with an out of the box solution, like Sophos or Netgear prosafe, I am sure there are others, But most out of the box solutions are more expensive than home users are willing to pay for. A dual wan router setup allows you to increase your internet bandwidth. You can load balance traffic for your specific needs. You can get internet connection redundancy and fail-over.

Regards,