# I cannot connect to more than one internet connection in my windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet

I have windows 8.1 installed on my PC. I have 3 wired broadband connections, but I cannot connect to two or more connections at a time. For example I want to use all three connections jointly to download torrent files and other files using Internet Download Manager. How do I achieve this in Windows 8.1? When I manually connect, I get the error saying "You can only connect to one connection at a time".

Is there a cost-effective solution (I prefer software tweak) to use all three broadband connections for these programs in windows 8.1 or can I do something different if I switch my OS to Linux (probably Ubuntu). Please explain the steps if there is a way to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster internet](http://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet), also see [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/240122/can-i-combine-two-lans-into-one-to-get-double-speed)

Comment: it is http://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect more than one wired connection if your PC have 3 Ethernet adapters, however, most programs will only use the default gateway.

I don't think IDM or uTorrent can use more than one gateway, I only know how to set the default one.

To change the default gateway, do this:

1. Go to Network and Sharing Center and click Change adapter settings from left sidebar.
2. Hit Alt from keyboard, so top menu pops out, and click Advanced Settings
3. Select the default connection you want to use from Connections list, and click arrow up so many times that it is on top. Save changes by pressing OK.