# Combining multiple Mobile Phone Internet Connection (to get high speed)

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, tethering

I want to combine multiple mobile 4G internet(Jio) phone connection (Usb Tethering or hot spot) to get high speed internet on my Mac OS X.

Solution that i checked are -

1. Use paid software [speedify](https://speedify.com/). (costly)
2. Use Hardware [ZifiLink](https://www.amazon.in/ZifiLink-3x-Internet-Networks-Broadband/dp/B0725BGKL7/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) (costly)
3. First convert from usb to RJ45 (not sure how to do it without using multiple routers) then put Loadbalancer
4. Install software like [dispatch-proxy](https://github.com/alexkirsz/dispatch-proxy) (not sure how well will it perform)

If you know some very good/efficient way to do it, please mention it will help others as well ( because many people are working from remote location due to COVID-19)

Comment: no it is like force binding to particular interface. kind of static (not auto loadbalanced)

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to speed up? Browsing? Downloading simple files? Downloading from P2P networks (e.g. torrents)? Or Steam/Origin and the like? // Keep in mind that if you use the same mobile phone provider for all links, you may slow things down instead because the links can interfere with each other.

Comment: Also, if anything, this is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/660798, but certainly not of the question marked now.

Comment: Agree. I have to validate how well it will perform.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use a Router.

Long answer: Balancing over multiple connections is nothing, that OSX is very good at natively and you might run into problems with some software, that makes deeper assumptions than are (and stay) valid.

A tiny box running `pfSense` with multiple gateways will be easily able to do your network magic on the WAN side and expose a single link on the LAN side, to which you can connect your device(s)

In `pfSense` you start by creating your WAN connections individually, then combine them into a gateway group.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen Rieck Agree. I have to validate, how  much feasible/efficient will it be for given case